# MsSQL: unexpected DATETIME column formatting style by CONACAT

Tags: sql-server, datetime, concatenation

I faced something, which I cannot understand and cannot find the way to control it.
I have a table in MsSQL DB with column **A** of **datetime** type.
Simple select of A column shows this:

```
select A from dbo.xxx;
 
            A
-----------------------
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
1900-01-01 14:00:18.123
```

But, when I use CONCAT like this:

```
select CONCAT('', A) from dbo.xxx;
```

I get results like:

```
Jan  1 1900 12:00AM
Jan  1 1900  2:00PM
```

I would like to get results as in first select (without CONCAT) and I would not like to use additional conversions like:

```
convert(VARCHAR, A, 121)
```

How can I influence CONCAT behaviour?

MsSQL: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU20) (KB5024276) - 15.0.4312.2 (X64)
Apr  1 2023 12:10:46
Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS)

Comment: If you want an explicit format then *explicitly* `CONVERT` the value with a style; don't rely on implicit conversion (especially when dates are involved).

Comment: That "simple select" gives you whatever format your client is choosing as the way to format date/times. It is in a literal sense impossible to get this format from the server without "additional conversions", because it doesn't know how things are formatted. So that `CONVERT` is the only way. Best, of course, is to have no need for manipulating dates as strings on the server side at all.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thank you for your reply. How can I, as a client, choose another way to format datetime?

Comment: That depends on your client. SQL Server is not like (say) MySQL where this is a driver setting and values are sent across as strings -- the `DATETIME` is sent as its true binary value, which your client then translates into a string on its own. That said, `sqlcmd` (SQL Server's own tool) has a confusing `-R` option that "causes sqlcmd to localize numeric, currency, date, and time columns retrieved from SQL Server based on the client's locale. By default, these columns are displayed using the server's regional settings". I have no idea what "regional settings" it's referring to.

Comment: Just an aside... varchar without a length is risky.   Try varchar(50) for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CONCAT function use the default conversion of data for which DATETIME and SMALLDATETIME (that Microsoft advice you to change for DATE/DATETIME2...) are formatted as US-english style, while it is not the case for DATETIME2 or DATE that uses ISO SQL default format AAAA-MM-JJ...

Just CAST oor CONVERT those old style datatype to new on the fly and the expectd result will be correct :

```
select CONCAT('', CAST(A AS DATETIME2(0))) from dbo.xxx;
```